# Why doesn't count function return accurate results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 problems in this query:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, pd.PaymentDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, pd.PaymentDate) AS PDate,
    SUM(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Commercial' then PD.PropertyDetailsTotalAmount else 0 END) as CommercialIncome, 
    SUM(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Residential' then PD.PropertyDetailsTotalAmount else 0 END) as ResidentialIncome,
    COUNT(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Commercial' then PD.pk_PropertyDetails_PropertyDetailsID else 0 END) as TotalCommercialMaps,
    COUNT(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Residential' then PD.pk_PropertyDetails_PropertyDetailsID else 0 END) as TotalResidentialMaps
From PropertyDetails PD
     Inner Join Properties P
         ON PD.fk_Properties_ID= p.pk_Properties_ID
     Inner Join PropertyTypes PT
         ON PT.pk_PropertyTypes_PropertyTypeID= P.fk_PropertyTypes_ID
where
    PD.Paid= 1 
    --and PaymentDate >= @DateFrom AND PaymentDate < DATEADD(day,1,@DateTo)
Group By DATENAME(MONTH, pd.PaymentDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, pd.PaymentDate)
```

Problems:

1. The count lines doesn't return the actual count, it even returns same count even if I write something else instead of 'Commercial/Residential'
2. I want to get the sum of both counts i.e. TotalCommercialResidentialMaps but when i do that, it throws error:

   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I tried a lot but doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any information about the "wrongness", ie. can you give an example of data that it counts, the value it produced and the value you expected? I'm pretty sure COUNT returns accurate results, assuming the underlying database doesn't have problems, like corrupt indexes or similar.

Comment: Also, please focus on one question at a time, otherwise you may get answers here that individually only answer parts of your questions, this makes it hard/impossible to select one answer as "Accepted", simply because no single answer qualifies.

Comment: Please post sample data, expected results and actual results - it's really hard to debug a query without this. However, I'd guess that you are trying to apply a "where" clause in the "Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Commercial' then PD.PropertyDetailsTotalAmount else 0 END" bit, which is almost certainly the problem.

Comment: Also, are you aware that `SUM(X)` where `X` is sometimes the value `0` still counts that value?

Comment: Ok sir, i will. Count return same result for both commercial and residential.

Comment: `Count` will also count the value `0`. perhaps you need to change that to `null`.

Comment: Use `NULL` instead of `0` in those `CASE` expressions. `SUM(X)` counts `0` as well.

Comment: So how to correct it, I have spent a day on it but finally arrived here, and will learn how to ask questions etc. I really will. But I also need help with this query.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - I'd love to know why you're focussing on `SUM()` with zeroes. I know of no way to distinguish `1+2` from `1+2+0+0` in a meaningful way, even in SQL. It matters for `COUNT`. It matter for `AVG`. `SUM`... not so much.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write COUNT. Not enough coffee this early.

Answer (score 4):

`COUNT(X)` counts `0` so these expressions:

```
COUNT(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Commercial' then PD.pk_PropertyDetails_PropertyDetailsID else 0 END)
```

will count all rows, assuming `PD.pk_PropertyDetails_PropertyDetailsID` is non-null.

To get `COUNT(X)` to *not* count a row, `X` will need to be `NULL`.

So change your case expressions to:

```
COUNT(Case when .... else NULL end)
                          ^^^^
```

This should give you your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that Lasse V. Karlsen has given is correct. Another idiom that you might see that accomplishes the same thing is:

```
SUM(Case when PT.PropertyTypeName = 'Commercial' then 1 else 0 end)
```

I like to think of this as going through the result creating tally marks and summing them up is equivalent to counting them.